# Connect Flutter application to DynamoDb database

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, amazon-dynamodb

I am developing a flutter application and my database is DynamoDB tables. I tried searching for ways to connect the DynamoDB database into my flutter application but couldn't do it. How do I connect it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to know about these services, before connecting your flutter app

1. Api Gateway - Service used to create a Rest API, which links the flutter app to cloud.
2. Lambda - This service sits in the middle, connecting the Api to your database ( DynamoDB ). Basically a function, it also states how the data is collected.

Try these tutorial

https://medium.com/avmconsulting-blog/how-to-build-a-serverless-api-with-dynamodb-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-d61ac63c27dd

Answer (score 2):

It is actually pretty easy.

1. First add [this](https://pub.dev/packages/aws_dynamodb_api) package to your project.
2. Then create your models you want to read and write. Along with conversion methods.

```dart
class Parent {
   String name;
   late List<Child> children;

 
  factory Parrent.fromDBValue(Map<String, AttributeValue> dbValue) {
    name = dbValue["name"]!.s!;
    children = dbValue["children"]!.l!.map((e) =>Child.fromDB(e)).toList();
  }


  Map<String, AttributeValue> toDBValue() {
    Map<String, AttributeValue> dbMap = Map();
    dbMap["name"] = AttributeValue(s: name);
    dbMap["children"] = AttributeValue(
        l: children.map((e) => AttributeValue(m: e.toDBValue())).toList());
    return dbMap;
  }
}
```

(AttributeValue comes from the package)

Then you can consume dynamo db api as per normal.

3. Create Dynamo service

```dart
class DynamoService {
  final service = DynamoDB(
      region: 'af-south-1',
      credentials: AwsClientCredentials(
          accessKey: "someAccessKey",
          secretKey: "somesecretkey"));

  Future<List<Map<String, AttributeValue>>?> getAll(
      {required String tableName}) async {
    var reslut = await service.scan(tableName: tableName);
    return reslut.items;
  }

  Future insertNewItem(Map<String, AttributeValue> dbData, String tableName) async {
    service.putItem(item: dbData, tableName: tableName);
  }
}
```

Then you can convert when getting all data from dynamo.

```dart
List<Parent> getAllParents() {
   List<Map<String, AttributeValue>>? parents =
        await dynamoService.getAll(tableName: "parents");
  return parents!.map((e) =>Parent.fromDbValue(e)).toList()
}
```

You can check all Dynamo operations from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.ReadItem.html)

Comment: How to fetch particular data by using "WHERE" ,"BETWEEN" conditions